# Automatically adjust Russia on the map (Mathematica 10.0)

Tags: bugs, geography

**Bug introduced in 10.0.0 and fixed in 10.1**

---

I'm using Mathematica 10.0 on Windows 10.
If I take a map of any country (even continent), it automatically adjusts the size of the map.

```
GeoGraphics[Polygon@EntityClass["Country", "Europe"]]
```

[image]

Except of Russia that reflects the whole map.

```
GeoGraphics[Polygon@Entity["Country", "Russia"]]
```

[image]

Is it a sort of a bug for Mathematica **V 10.0**? Can somebody reproduce this behaviour of the Russian map?

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem. See "answer" below.

Comment: Editing my answer/extended-comment is not the appropriate way to comment on it. Better to edit your question to show any clarification of it.

Comment: That I get what I think is a correct result for your code indicates that your problem is localized. It may be a V10.0 issue, a Window issue, or  just that you experience a kernel glitch. Have you tried evaluating your code in new _Mathematica_ session?

Comment: @m_goldberg, Yes, I have reloaded the system and MMA session, it persists.

Comment: That seems to narrow it down to Windows or V10.0. That takes me out of the game. I don't have access to such software.

Comment: @m_goldberg, may you try this code? `GeoGraphics[GeoRange -> Entity["Country", "Russia"]]`. Should I delete the question?

Comment: @garej Please, do not delete the question. It is relevant for other people with the same version. There is also specific tag `bugs` for *confirmed* bugs.

Comment: @ybeltukov Is this really a bug though? it's just giving a non aesthetic, yet correct plot.

Comment: @ChipHurst You know, there is no certain edge. It looks like undesired behavior. All other countries looks much better and the answer depends on your origin :)

Comment: in Soviet Russia, planet adjusts to fit country.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is version 10.0 specific bug. Please upgrade to a more recent version

Version 10.0.0:

[image]

Version 10.1 and above:

[image]

Tested on Linux. It seems that other OS have the same behavior.

---

One can extract proper options from recent version and put them to 10.0.0:

```
GeoGraphics[Polygon@Entity["Country", "Russia"],
 GeoProjection -> {"LambertAzimuthal", 
     "Centering" -> GeoPosition[{59.4954, 105.06}]}, GeoRange -> All, 
 GeoZoomLevel -> 3, PlotRange -> {{-0.884836, 0.884836}, {-0.349549, 
       0.531066}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Mother Russia is still too big :)

Comment: @ybeltukov, may I ask you to check also this `GeoListPlot[
 Polygon@Entity["AdministrativeDivision", {"Chukotka", "Russia"}], 
 GeoRange -> {{40, 80}, {0, 200}}, GeoProjection -> "Albers"]`. I have a part of Chukotka not included. (is it due to `GeoProjection`?)

Comment: @garej I get [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/pHem7.png) in version 10.0.0. I propose to use my last example in the answer.

Answer (score 5):

I have the same difficulties with 10.0 on Windows. The best I can get to display the complete area of Russia is

```
GeoGraphics[Polygon @ Entity["Country", "Russia"], 
 GeoProjection -> "Mercator",
 GeoRange -> {{40, 80}, {25, 195}}, 
 ImageSize -> 600]
```

**Update**

To also show Kaliningrad in the far west

```
GeoGraphics[{
  PointSize[0.02],
  Point[GeoPosition[Entity["City", {"Kaliningrad", "Kaliningrad", "Russia"}]]],
  Polygon@Entity["Country", "Russia"]},
 GeoProjection -> "Mercator",
 GeoRange -> {{40, 80}, {18, 195}},
 ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

Comment: add some space to the left, Kaliningrad left outside =))

Comment: Of course ! See update :)

Answer (score 3):

This is not an answer; it is a comment that needs to show an image.

I don't get what you show from

```
GeoGraphics[Polygon @ Entity["Country", "Russia"]]
```

I get

[image: map]

I evaluated your code with V10.3 running on OS X 10.10.2.